# Google Apps Script: Use array out of spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, loops, spreadsheet

I try to use Google Script Apps (instead of VBA which I am more used to) and managed now to create a loop over different spreadsheets (and not only different sheets in one document) using the forEach function.
(I tried with a for (r=1;r=lastRow; r++) but I did not manage).

It is working now defining the array for the sheetnames manually:
`var SheetList = ["17DCu1nyyX4a6zCkkT3RfBSfo-ghoc2fXEX8chlVMv5k", "1rRGQHs_JShPSBIGFCdG6AqXM967JFhdlfQ92cf5ISL8", "1pFDyXgYmvC5gnN5AU5xJ8vGiihwtubcbG2n4LPhPACQ", "1mK_X4Q7ysJQTt8NZoZASBE5zuUllPmmWSJsxu5Dnu9Y", "1FpjIGWTG5_6MMYJF72wvoiBRp_Xlt5BDpzvSZKcsU"]`

And then for information the loop:

```
SheetList.forEach(function(r) {
    var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(r)
    var thisData = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Actions').getDataRange()

    var values = thisData.getValues();

    var toWorksheet = targetSpreadsheetID.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName); 
    var last = toWorksheet.getLastRow ()+ 1
    var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(last, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())

    toRange.setValues(values);
    })
```

Now I want to create the definition of the array "automatically" out of the spreadsheet 'List' where all spreadsheets which I want to loop are listed in column C.

I tried several ideas, but always failed.
Most optimistic ones were:

```
var SheetList = targetSpreadsheetID.getSheetByName('List').getRange(2,3,lastRow-2,3).getValues()
```

And I also tried with the array-function:

```
var sheetList=Array.apply(targetSpreadsheetID.getSheetByName('List').getRange(2,3,lastRow-2,3))
```

but all without success.
It should be possible normally in more or less one single line to import the array from the speadsheet to the Google apps scripts?
I would very much appreciate if someone could please give me a hint where my mistake is.

Thank you very much.
Maria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still did not manage to put the array as I wanted it initially, but now I found a workable solution with the For Loop which I want to share here in case someone is looking for a similar solution (and then finds at least my workaround ;) )

```
for (i=2; i<lastRow;i++){
   var SheetList = targetSpreadsheetID.getSheetByName('List').getRange(i,3).getValues() 
    Logger.log(SheetList);
    var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SheetList); 
    ... // the rest identical to loop above...
```

Don't hesitate to add your comments or advice anyhow, but I will mark the question as closed.

Thanks a lot.

Maria